# For an android virtual device emulator which target should i target it to? (Image included)

Tags: emulators, avd-manager

[image: This is a screenshot of what i am trying to do.]

It says that the CPU,ABI system image isn't available for this target, but there is only one target and thats the one that is already selected. What do i do? Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the android sdk manager and download the image because you only have the device definitions and the SDK and  not the system images  so download them from there

Comment: wait, it still doesn't work, i don't care what device it works on. Can you tell me what exactly im supposed to download?

Comment: in the sdk manager download the image of the api you are working on if you are using KitKat(API 19 ) download the api 19 system images , SDK manager groupe them for you together so it will be easy to do that

Comment: when i make a new android application on eclipse, is the API im working with the mimimum required SDK, target SDK, or the compile with option in the new application window? I set all of them to API 20, and installed all the API 20 system images, but it in the AVD manager, it still gives me the same error. What do i do?

Comment: put them to api 19 , API 20 us the android wear smartwatch , and everything will work , and accept my answer

Comment: what should I put in the compile with option? It only has API 20